# Can't define variables in modules

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with 2 variables in this code `nmin` and `ns`, I guess it is a modularization problem.

```
def le():
    ns=0
    nmin=0
    my_list=[]
    while True:    
        s=input('enter the salary ')
        if s=='': break
        s=float(s)
        ns=ns+1  #couting the numbers of salaries (s) typed (says undefined)
        bonus=s*0.2
        if bonus < 100:
            bonus=100
            nmin=nmin+1  #couting the numbers minimal bonuses (says undefined)
        my_list.append(s)
        my_list.append(bonus)
        return my_list, nmin, ns


def calculos(my_list):
    vmax=my_list[1]
    total=0
    for i in  my_list[1::2]:
        total=total + i
    for i in my_list[1::2]:
        if i > vmax:
            vmax=i
    return vmax, total

def printing(my_list, vmax, total, nmin, ns ):
        print('The total amount spent on bonus is R${:5.2f}'.format(total))
        print('The number of salaries if {2d}'. format(ns))
        print('The highest bonus amount paid is R${:5.2f}'.format(vmax))
        print('The number of minimal bonuses is {2d}'.format(nmin))
        return 



my_list= le()
vmax, total= calculos(my_list)
write= printing(my_list, vmax, total, nmin, ns)*
```

I returned them in the first module, used as arguments on `def printing` and in the main, calling the modules. Still, it stays `undefined` on the last line.

PS: when I remove them off the whole code, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `nmin` and `ns` aren't defined in the main scope, they are local variables in the scope of the function `le`, and it returns values, not the variables. So one alternative is to make it global, this way all the functions and scopes will have access to the variables. The other is to correctly attribute the return of the function.

```
my_list, nmin, ns = le()
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because your function `def le()` returned a tuple of values, which in turn are stored in variable `my_list` which of `tuple` type.

Since the value are stored in a `tuple` they can be accessed only by the tuple variable. What you are trying to do is, return a pool/tuple of values off a function, and treat every returned value as a separate variable. Which was only true if you stored the returning values into separate variables like `x, y, z = le()`, which you didn't.

**RECTIFICATION:-**

**METHOD 1:-**

```
write = printing(my_list, vmax, total, my_list[1], my_list[2])
```

**METHOD 2:-**

```
my_list, nmin, ns = le()
```

**METHOD 3:-**

```
def le():
    global ns
    global nmin
    ns = nmin = 0
```

**WORKING OF EACH METHOD:-**

1. First method obtains the values of `nmin` and `ns` via indexing them from the tuple in which their values are stored in (sort of)
2. Second method, stores the values of returned tuple into separate three separate variables `my_list`, `nmin` and `ns` variables
3. Third method, makes the scope of variables `nmin` and `ns` global such that they can be accessed throughout the scope of our current program **(generally won't recommend this method)**